# BibTeX: Prevent line break after "et al." citation

Tags: line-breaking, natbib

BibTeX adds a whitespace after a citation like "et al.". 
If this occurs at the end of a line, the year can be in the next line.

I think this can be misleading at the end of a line, because it could be mistakenly read as the end of a line and then the number at the beginnning of the next line looks odd.

In my opinion, this interrupts the flow of reading, but I am also interested in your point of view.

For suppressing the line break, I haven't been lazy and did a web search for a solution.

I found the suggestion to use `\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addnbspace}`, but this did unfortunately not work in my hands.

I think this is because of the fact that the `\nameyeardelim` macro is only provided by the `biblatex` package, which I am not using (and also can't use, because I am generating the tex file via *RStudio*'s *bookdown* package.

Could anyone point me towards another possible way to prevent the line break after a "et al." citation?

Comment: Can you give us a short example document (and [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864)) to play around with, please? I think most details one would need to answer your question are already given, but it would help me get started with your question if I could see what you have so far. That way I don't have to spend my time guessing and recreating what you already have anyway.

Comment: I have removed the `biblatex` tag since you state that you can't use `biblatex`, so the question isn't really about `biblatex`.

Answer (score 5):

With `natbib` you can either use

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\NAT@spacechar}{~}
\makeatother
```

or

```
\bibpunct[, ]{\unskip~(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}
```

where the `\unskip~(` removes the space before the brackets and replaces it with a non-breaking space.

The `\NAT@spacechar` also turns other spaces inserted by `natbib`'s citation commands into unbreakable spaces, that might be wanted or unwanted. You can see where these spaces are if you replace the `~` in the code above by `XXX`.

The `\bibpunct` solution naturally overrides loading-time options such as `square` and `round` and sets other punctuation as well. If you use a special style you may have to adjust the value a bit.

`natbib.sty` explains `\bibpunct` as follows

> ```
> % Alternatively:
> % Use \bibpunct with 6 mandatory arguments:
> %    1. opening bracket for citation
> %    2. closing bracket
> %    3. citation separator (for multiple citations in one \cite)
> %    4. the letter n for numerical styles, s for superscripts
> %        else anything for author-year
> %    5. punctuation between authors and date
> %    6. punctuation between years (or numbers) when common authors missing
> % One optional argument is the character coming before post-notes. It
> %   appears in square braces before all other arguments. May be left off.
> % Example (and default) \bibpunct[, ]{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}
> ```

The pdf documentation also has something about it http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/natbib.pdf on p. 13.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helpful answer. Since I have many citations, which would be affected in an undesirable way by `\NAT@spacechar` this is difficult (but it is very interesting that this option exists!). What would help me a lot would be an explanation on the `\bibpunct` code: My citation would be something like `Einstein et al. (1919)`.  I use `apalike` as a citation style. Now I am not sure, whether the suggested could will interfere with other citations. Is there a way to get the default `\bibpunct` for `apalike`? Is it maybe even identical to what you wrote?

Comment: Thanks again so much. This is invaluable supported that I can't acknowledge enough.